# CSS pie spinner/loader with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css, spinner

I need to make a pie spinner/loader only using css and javascript.

So far I managed to make it work when the background is solid, since it's not need to see though the div that hides the semircircle (don't mind colors and tops/lefts):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

.wrapper,
.wrapper * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper .pie,
.wrapper * .pie {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper .spinner,
.wrapper * .spinner {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100%/50% 0 0 50%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-right: none;
  animation: rota 5s linear infinite
}

.wrapper .filler,
.wrapper * .filler {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0/0 50% 50% 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: none;
  background: red;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite reverse
}

.wrapper .mask,
.wrapper * .mask {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 300;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite
}

.wrapper:hover .spinner,
.wrapper:hover .filler,
.wrapper:hover .mask {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pie spinner"></div>
  <div class="pie filler"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is, I need to make the background transparent so I can see though it, but then the mask div becomes useless:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/20000/velka/tulip-flower-garden.jpg)
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.wrapper,
.wrapper * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper .pie,
.wrapper * .pie {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper .spinner,
.wrapper * .spinner {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100%/50% 0 0 50%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-right: none;
  animation: rota 5s linear infinite
}

.wrapper .filler,
.wrapper * .filler {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0/0 50% 50% 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: none;
  background: red;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite reverse
}

.wrapper .mask,
.wrapper * .mask {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 300;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite
}

.wrapper:hover .spinner,
.wrapper:hover .filler,
.wrapper:hover .mask {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pie spinner"></div>
  <div class="pie filler"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want? How?

Comment: You can use css gradient background rotation e.g. [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/BhtJI)

Comment: This it's almost what I want, the only problem is I can't use jQuery in this project, but I will research the gradient background rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent !important; 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

.wrapper,
.wrapper * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper .pie,
.wrapper * .pie {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper .spinner,
.wrapper * .spinner {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100%/50% 0 0 50%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-right: none;
  animation: rota 5s linear infinite
}

.wrapper .filler,
.wrapper * .filler {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0/0 50% 50% 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: none;
  background: red;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite reverse
}

.wrapper .mask,
.wrapper * .mask {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 300;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) infinite
}

.wrapper:hover .spinner,
.wrapper:hover .filler,
.wrapper:hover .mask {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pie spinner"></div>
  <div class="pie filler"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

add background transprent important

```
.wrapper { background: transparent !important; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the effect must be the same as the first snippet, it's like a circle that fills clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to set a timer to your loaders... this is an simple example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').addClass('pie spinner');
}, 3000); });
```

Comment: I'm not asking about "launching" the loader, I'm asking about how to make the mask div transparent, or another solution to achieve what I'm actually achieving in the first snippet/

Comment: Set `rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.11)` as a background for your .Wrapper .pie class and also on your .Wrapper .filler class